# Jquery Not loading on Second Page

Tags: jquery

Solved thanks to Matt!

So this is an odd bug ive come across redoing my new site. I have added a testimonial second on one page and it seems to have "broken" the smooth scroll Jquery I had working.

The Beta site is here... www.anim-house.co.uk You can see the scroll working fine. 
On www.anim-house.co.uk/portfolio.html The scroll does not work - the addition of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fade').list_ticker({
        speed:14000,
        effect:'fade'
    });     
});
```

Seems to have broken it? Im amateur when it comes to Jquery if someone could look through and figure out the error id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I should add that even removing the new code and reverting back to my old portfolio page the site still does not scroll.

Comment: jQuery is loading, open a debug console and type "jQuery"

Comment: var targetOffset = $target.offset().top; this line

Comment: `$target` is undefined. `var $target = $(this.hash)` sets target.

Comment: @Blender I do not think that is true.

Comment: @user1459873: `$.offset()` only returns `null` if the object doesn't exist. That means that `this.hash` isn't returning a selector that matches any element.

Comment: @Blender indeed, however that does not mean that target is being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() { console.log(this.hash)})
#contact
#cgi
#web-design
#graphic-design
#motion-graphics
#photography
#home
#cgi
#web-design
#graphic-design
#motion-graphics
#photography
#home
null
null
null
```

It is those last three that are causing the error. They are related to links with href="#". Instead of checking for

```
if(target) {
```

Check for

```
if ($target  && target) {
```

**EDIT**: OP got it working with this: http://paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

The website looks very nice, by the way.

Comment: As soon as get this bug fixed I will be over the moon. And thanks - Amateur web designer here trying to flex my muscles with this site.

Comment: Ive replaced  if(target) { with if ($target  && target) { on like 65, no effect.

Comment: Just uploaded the latest code on index + portfolio line 65 has been edited how you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your portfolio.html:

This is what I got from the Chrome dev-tools:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined  at line 66

The affected line is:

var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

After getting that error, the browser stops processing and your plugin is likely not loaded. Fixing this error should fix the rest as well (provided there are no other errors)

Comment: How is it working on my index page then? And how would I go about fixing this bug.. Like I say im a noob at jQuery.

Comment: @Alex the error is caused by links that have href="#", which you have on the portfolio page and not your index.

Comment: My navigation menue works the same on both. They all link to ID Anchors? Sorry Im not understanding how to fix it still heh.

Comment: @Alex What you are doing is kind of a hack.  It is relying on the coincidental fact that the css selector by ID starts with a hash, and so do internal anchors in a URI.  This is not a big problem because it works, but you need to check that the referenced element exists before trying to do stuff on it.  In this case, simply checking "if($target && target) {" should do that for you, but if you want a more robust solution, you need to use something like this: http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

Comment: I could kiss you matt!
Thank you so much. Ive spent the better part of a day trying to hack this to get it to work heh. 

Thank you, my net trawling skills have failed me that code was perfect. Thank you so much again!

Comment: No problem... we all need to start somewhere. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Thanks you too pal :)
Linkedin Perhaps? A Budding young one such as myself needs all the connections he can get.

Comment: @Alex'Fonz'Bennett sure: be.linkedin.com/pub/matthew-hawker/41/8ba/83b/